# Translating Views Exposed filters Label

Tags: internationalization, drupal-views

I'm trying to translate the views exposed filters **labels** on my site.
i manage to have the exposed filters themselves translated with the Internationalization Views module. I tried the string override module to translate the exposed filters labels but so far no luck. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Well,
actually I manage to find it myself.

it's just a matter of visiting /admin/structure/views/settings/advanced

there in the localization options choose 'core'.

Then all strings in views (Exposed filters labels included) become translatable via the string override module.

Seems like Internationalization Views changes that setting by default. Reverting it makes everything work as it should.

Comment: Thanx a million!!! Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me :/ Core was already selected, yet the strings I try to override don't come through.

Comment: Actually that's a lie. What I am trying to change is not the label but the - Any - selection inside the filter (using better exposed filters). I guess it might have to do with how that module accesses translations.